Swagger UI giving 404 error with Springboot2
I'm migrating a springboot 2.7.18 application from springfox-swagger to springdoc-openapi.
Did configuration and added properties etc., but getting the below in catalina logs when trying to access /swagger-ui/index.html, /swagger-ui.html, /v3/api-docs/swagger-config, /v3/api-docs etc.
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [api] threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This method cannot decide whether these patterns are Spring MVC patterns or not. If this endpoint is a Spring MVC endpoint, please use requestMatchers(MvcRequestMatcher); otherwise, please use requestMatchers(AntPathRequestMatcher).

This is because there is more than one mappable servlet in your servlet context: {com.abc.def.controller.servlet.ScepServletIermpl=[/c/scep/*], org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet=[], com.abc.def.controller.servlet.ScepServletImpl=[/c/scep-internal], com.abc.def.controller.servlet.CDNServletImpl=[/cdn/*], org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet=[*.jspx, *.jsp], org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet=[], org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet=[/c/d/e/f.svc]}.

For each MvcRequestMatcher, call MvcRequestMatcher#setServletPath to indicate the servlet path.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:219)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry$DispatcherServletRequestMatcher.matches(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:631)
        at org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher.matches(OrRequestMatcher.java:58)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry$DispatcherServletDelegatingRequestMatcher.requestMatcher(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:666)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry$DispatcherServletDelegatingRequestMatcher.matches(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:674)
        at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry$DeferredRequestMatcher.matches(AbstractRequestMatcherRegistry.java:595)
        at org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain.matches(DefaultSecurityFilterChain.java:72)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.RequestMatcherDelegatingWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.getDelegate(RequestMatcherDelegatingWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.java:120)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.RequestMatcherDelegatingWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.isAllowed(RequestMatcherDelegatingWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator.java:71)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter.isAllowed(ErrorPageSecurityFilter.java:88)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageSecurityFilter.java:76)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.ErrorPageSecurityFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageSecurityFilter.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:352)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:108)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:91)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:164)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at com.abc.def.controller.filter.BasicPinAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicPinAuthenticationFilter.java:82)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at com.abc.def.controller.filter.PartnerAccountNonceBasedAuthFilter.doFilter(PartnerAccountNonceBasedAuthFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
        at com.abc.def.security.authentication.saml.SAMLAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(SAMLAuthenticationFilter.java:83)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint.doFilter(SAMLEntryPoint.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at com.abc.def.security.authentication.saml.SAMLLoginRedirectFilter.doFilter(SAMLLoginRedirectFilter.java:129)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at com.abc.def.common.auth.filter.CookieAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CookieAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at com.abc.def.controller.filter.MdmOidcProviderPartialAuthFilter.doFilter(MdmOidcProviderPartialAuthFilter.java:67)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at com.abc.def.controller.filter.ValidTokenCheckFilter.doFilter(ValidTokenCheckFilter.java:82)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at com.abc.def.security.authentication.LoginNonceAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(LoginNonceAuthenticationFilter.java:89)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at com.abc.def.controller.filter.UiMetadataApiFilter.doFilter(UiMetadataApiFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at com.abc.def.controller.filter.DeepLinkIdentificationFilter.doFilter(DeepLinkIdentificationFilter.java:53)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at com.abc.def.controller.filter.TenantSuppressionExceptionHandlerFilter.doFilter(TenantSuppressionExceptionHandlerFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at com.abc.def.controller.filter.SessionInactivityTimeoutFilter.doFilter(SessionInactivityTimeoutFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:142)
        at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:82)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:361)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:225)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.web.servlet.TracingFilter.doFilter(TracingFilter.java:68)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.autoconfig.instrument.web.TraceWebServletConfiguration$LazyTracingFilter.doFilter(TraceWebServletConfiguration.java:131)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:661)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:357)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:294)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:237)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:670)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:765)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1790)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Expected that Swagger UI will be displayed. However, it is not working like that.

It doesn't work with Spring Boot 2.7, you have to use at least 3.1 version.
